# "administration" tag should be blacklisted

Tags: discussion, tagging

I find the tag [administration](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/administration) really useless.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It does seem entirely redundant and overbroad, and the questions in it are all tagged with other tags (and have no particular unifying feature).  Death to it.